# Having trouble with iHover git project

Tags: css, hover, css-transforms

I am trying to use the iHover git project effect but can only get it partially working. Here is the link to the github demo and files

http://gudh.github.io/ihover/dist/index.html (demo)
https://github.com/gudh/ihover

I've setup a temporary fake page to try and mimic the demo. I've downloaded the files and uploaded all the CSS and linked it. It says all you need is the CSS and your good to go. But I don't get that because I have linked it and it isn't working. Please help.

Here is my test site:
http://circleton.mybnbwebsite.com/

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <!-- normal -->

        <div class="ih-item circle effect2 left_to_right">
            <div class="img"><img alt="img" src=
            "http://gudh.github.io/ihover/dist/images/assets/4.jpg"></div>

            <div class="info">
                <h3>Heading here</h3>

                <p>Description goes here</p>
            </div>
        </div><!-- end normal -->
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <!-- colored -->

        <div class="ih-item circle colored effect2 left_to_right">
            <div class="img"><img alt="img" src=
            "http://gudh.github.io/ihover/dist/images/assets/5.jpg"></div>

            <div class="info">
                <h3>Heading here</h3>

                <p>Description goes here</p>
            </div>
        </div><!-- end colored -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am using bootstrap and I've heard that it doesn't work with bootstrap. But still would love some feedback.

Comment: It works fine with bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an anchor:

```
  <div class="ih-item circle colored effect2 left_to_right">
      <a href="#"> <!-- your code does not have this or the matching end tag -->
          <div class="img">
              <img src="http://gudh.github.io/ihover/dist/images/assets/5.jpg"
alt="img" />
         </div>

         <div class="info">
             <h3>Heading here</h3>

             <p>Description goes here</p>
         </div>
      </a>
  </div>
```

Much of their code depends on the `:hover` pseudo element to do the transforms (rotate, translate, etc). So without the anchor, it won't work correctly.

```
.ih-item.circle.effect2.left_to_right a:hover .img {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```

[image]

Comment: It works if you use the markup *exactly* as I wrote it and correct a couple of css rules on ``info`` class. The ``info`` class is hidden because you are setting ``opacity: 0!important;`` on ``info``. Remove that and then you'll see the text as well. FWIW, you are overriding some css properties with ``!important``. You should not get in the habit of doing this. Learn how to style correctly. https://smacss.com/